# wait for data arrive from serial port in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I use serial port connection in my qt application.
My problem- I cant get back the control (or the values comes from the comm port) after sending the command.

I have a class named serial.cpp which responsible to serial port connection.
This class contains 2 queues. one for save bytes from the comm port and second for the decoded messages. the class has the functions below:

```
void Serial::sendCommand(QString s)
{
    QString sometext = s;
    QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromHex(sometext.toLatin1());
    serial->write(ba);
}

void Serial::serialReceived()
{
    QByteArray ba ;
    serialArray = serial->readAll();
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(serialArray);i++)
    {
        queueBytes.enqueue(serialArray[i]);  // queue for saving the bytes
    }

    QVector<int> vect = queueBytes.toVector();

    packetSize = 6;
    if (vect.size() >= packetSize)
    { // the whole packet arrived
        for (int i =0 ;i<packetSize;i++)
        {
            item = queueBytes.dequeue();
            ba.append(item);
        }
    }
    if (ba.toHex() == "12ee02010176")
        queueMsgs.enqueue("ACK");

    // ... and so on
}
```

here is the call class:

```
void Engine::onNewMessageFromAppReceived(int msgId,QString args)
{
    serial->sendCommand("ee1203190209005569");

    while (serial->queueMsgs.size() == 0) // infinite loop-the queue is always empty
    {
        usleep(1);
    }

    QVector<QString> vect2 = serial->queueMsgs.toVector();
    qDebug() << vect2 << "get ack---" ;
}
```

please your help

Comment: Looks like your loop blocks the event loop. You don't show how these methods are getting called, so it's impossible to say how you should fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`QSerialPort`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) class inherits from [`QIODevice`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) which has `waitFor...` methods that may be what you're looking for. Take a look at [these docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html).

If you want to handle the serial port asynchronously, use the `readyRead` signal and perform reading in a function that you connected to that signal. If you don't mind that the operation is blocking, the `waitForReadyRead` function is what you're looking for.

### The good way

Here's the proper way to do it using [Qt's signals and slots mechanism](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). This **will not block** your GUI and lets your application respond to user actions even while you are waiting for the serial port.

1. Connect a function to the `bytesWritten` signal
   The code you want to execute after you sent data through the serial port should be placed in this function.
2. Connect a function to the `readyRead` signal
   The code you want to execute after you read some data from the serial port should be placed in this function.
3. Open the port

### The bad way

In some cases you can do it like this, but it's **blocking**, meaning that your GUI will freeze while your app is waiting for the serial port. I don't recommend doing it like this.

1. Open the port
2. Send data
3. Call `waitForBytesWritten`
4. Call `waitForReadyRead`

### Working example code

Qt has a [vast amount of working example code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html). There are even [examples about how to use `QSerialPort`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-examples.html), and they are well worth checking out. You might be most interested in the [async writer example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-cwriterasync-example.html) and the [async reader example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-creaderasync-example.html).

Comment: @hyde Yes, I said that in my answer.

Comment: so basically, i need to replace the while loop in : serial.waitForReadyRead() ? i also tried before the signsl option but no success. i had the same problem ...

Comment: this is a gui program. i tried the signal & slot mechanism but had the same problem. i send command to serial port but the code after the sending run before the slot executed. i updated the queue in the slot but couldnt get the values in the code comes after. what is the best practice for this use case?

Comment: @NatiLerner I added more details to my answer.

Comment: I posted another question , appreciate if you take a look   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500236/handling-recieved-messages-from-serial-port-in-qt