# handling recieved messages from serial port in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

after the responses I got from  [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489754/wait-for-data-arrive-from-serial-port-in-qt)
I made some changes in my code. my architecture now is manged by signal and slot mechanism.

I am using 3 layers / modules in my application.

- the app layer (used for handling the gui)
- the engine  (used for handling the business logic an the protocol)
- the serial (used for handling the bytes to send and read from the comm port)

In my engine class I want to send command only if I get acknowledge from the serial port. I am really trying to understand how can I send a serial collection of commands (each command depends on the previous command ) while everything here is asynchronous.

is this the correct way to do this?

**Here the piece of code: (the relevant)**

singlepulse.cpp   // the form widget

in  the constructor:

```
engine = new Engine();
connect(this,SIGNAL(sendMessageToEngine(int,QString)),
        engine,SLOT(onNewMessageFromAppReceived(int,QString)));
connect(engine,SIGNAL(sendMessageToApp(QString)),
        this,SLOT(onNewMessageFromEngineReceived(QString)));
```

rest of the code:

```
void SinglePulse::on_btnStartOperation_clicked()
{
    emit sendMessageToEngine(1);
}

void SinglePulse::onNewMessageFromEngineReceived(QString s)
{
}
```

engine.cpp :

```
Engine::Engine(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    serial = new Serial();
    connect(this,SIGNAL(sendMessageToSerial(QString)),
            serial,SLOT(onNewMessageToSendReceived(QString)));
    connect(serial,SIGNAL(sendMessageToEngine(QByteArray)),
            this,SLOT(onNewMessageFromSerialReceived(QByteArray)));
}

void Engine::onNewMessageFromAppReceived(int msgId)
{
    ackArrived = false;
    if (msgId == 1)
    {
        emit sendMessageToSerial("ee120301fe09000261");  
        // here I want to check if acknowledge is arrived and if so - send the next command    
        if (ackArrived)
        {
            emit sendMessageToSerial("ee120145512400261");  //send here the next command
        }
    }
}

void Engine::onNewMessageFromSerialReceived(QByteArray b)
{
    ackArrived = false;
    QString hexValues;
    QString decodedMsg;
    hexValues = b.toHex();

    if (hexValues == "12ee02010176")
    {
        qDebug() << QDateTime::currentDateTime() << "get ack" ;
        decodedMsg = "ACK";
        ackArrived = true;
    }
}
```

serial.cpp:

```
Serial::Serial()
{
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
    serial->setPortName("ttyS0");
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    connect(serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(serialReceived()));
}

void Serial::onNewMessageToSendReceived(QString s)
{
    QString sometext = s;
    QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromHex(sometext.toLatin1());
    serial->write(ba);
}

void Serial::serialReceived()
{
    QByteArray ba;

    ba = serial->readAll();
    qDebug() << ba.toHex();
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(ba);i++)
        queueBytes.enqueue(ba[i]);

    int item;
    int packetSize;
    QByteArray baToSend;
    QVector<int> vect = queueBytes.toVector();

    if (vect[2] == 2)   // flow control
    {
        packetSize = 6;
        if (vect.size() >= packetSize)
        {  // the whole packet arrived
            for (int i =0 ;i<packetSize;i++)
            {
                item = queueBytes.dequeue();
                baToSend.append(item);
            }
            emit sendMessageToEngine(baToSend);
        }
    }
    else if (vect[2] == 3)   // data token packet
    {
        packetSize = vect[3];
        if (vect.size() >= packetSize)
        {   // the whole packet arrived
            for (int i =0 ;i<packetSize;i++)
            {
                item = queueBytes.dequeue();
                baToSend.append(item);
            }
            emit sendMessageToEngine(baToSend);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will not work this way. emit are either asynchronous, so you'll fail the ackReceived test, or synchronous, and it will freeze your main loop and you'll not receive the ack as well.
You need to use 1) a thread or 2) a sequence of connect/emit/disconnect, or 3) a Command pattern chain (see design patterns).

Comment: it seems very complicated. what do i need to search for the thread solution?

Comment: @Natile What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: for now I want something very simple: send 5 command to serial port one after the other. after every command i need to check if there is a response from the microcontroller, output the response into textbox. if there is no response from microcontroller for 1 sec, it will output "no response" to that textbox. the next command will be send only after the response arrived or 1 second passed. al  of this flow should be started from pressing on button in the gui. thats all for now

Comment: @Venemo , thank for trying to help me, its frustrating

Comment: @Natile Don't worry, it's always a bit hard when you're doing stuff like this for the first time. Did you look at the example code in my answer to your previous question?

Comment: @Venemo Yes I do. i read this and it was help me to undestand the concept but i am still having trouble. now i try to use a thread like the suggest above and i have the same problem. please check my code and tell me what i can do.

Comment: @Venemo , can i send you my code ? its just  2 classes

Comment: You should first understand how threads work in Qt. I suggest this blog post. https://codethis.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/using-qthread-without-subclassing/ . Another option is to use QExtSerialPort with signal/slots, and a proper finite state machine.